# Mongoose query to check array contains element or not in mongoose query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have records like this..

```
{
                "photo": "default.jpg",
                "roles": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5f44d77be830263684eb7914",
                        "name": "Test",
                        "__v": 0
                    }
                ],
                "_id": "5f44d2f4ff04993b40684bf9",
                "name": "Test User",
                "email": "test@gmail.com",             
                "id": "5f44d2f4ff04993b40684bf9"
}
```

i want to  weather the role user trying to delete is in use or not. for this i have write a query but it always return an empty array.

```
const check = await User.find({roles: {$elemMatch: {_id: req.params.id}}});
```

these are the queries i checked in compass but it always an array

```
{"roles._id":"5f44d77be830263684eb7914"}
{roles: $elemMatch: {_id: "5f44d77be830263684eb7914"}}
```

my User document hass roles field something like this.

```
 roles:[
  {
    type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:"Roles",
    validate: {
      validator: async function(v) {
        return await Roles.findById(v, (err, rec) => rec !== null)
      },
      message: 'Invalid Object ID'
    },
    required:true
  }
],
```

IS there any way to enforce integrity constraint like if user tries to delete records which have dependencies on other records then we should not allow user to delete this record.

Comment: write code in correct format....

Comment: @turivishal same empty array

Comment: you should have to check the id that you have passed in `req.params.id` or check this in compass `{roles._id: ObjectId("5f44d77be830263684eb7914")}`, confirm the same id you have in collection. what is the format of _id in collection its string or object id?

Comment: roles is an array of objects where each object  ObjectId referencing to roles document. Query you provided to me is not valid its not working on compass